# Azure Data Factory publish branch confusion

Tags: git, github, azure-data-factory

1. Create a local branch
2. Select in ADF - branch drop down
3. Add/modify pipelines. (changes are automatically saved in local
   branch in GIT when you save)
4. Push changes from local branch to master (collaboration) branch
5. Select master branch in ADF
6. Now publish to _publish branch
7. Merge _publish back to Master

This is the standard process in ADF git integration. The resulting publish branch to be used for release is _publish. But this is different from master. What if we want to add creation of storage accounts and other improvements on the '_publish' branch? Should we create a feature branch from _publish?

Or in other words, between #4 and #7 other devs could also impact the branches. How can we make _publish and it's contents a 'master' branch?